# Continuous bijection with continuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ an arbitrary inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$\|\cdot\|$ the norm induced by this inner product. Consider the function
$f:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ given by $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\|x\|^2}$.

I need to show that $f$ is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse.

> First of all, I showed that $f$ is injective.
>
> Consider $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$, then $\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}=\dfrac{y}{||y||^2}$.
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \dfrac{x}{||x||^2}=\dfrac{y}{||y||^2} &\Rightarrow&  \left\|\dfrac{x}{||x||^2} \right\|=\left\|\dfrac{y}{||y||^2} \right\|\\
> &\Rightarrow&  \dfrac{||x||}{||x||^2}=\dfrac{||y||}{||y||^2} \\
> &\Rightarrow& \dfrac{1}{||x||}=\dfrac{1}{||y||} \\
> &\Rightarrow& ||x||=||y||\\
> \end{eqnarray*}
> Therefore, $\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}=\dfrac{y}{||x||^2} \Rightarrow x=y$.

> Now, to show that $f$ is continuous. Consider $x_k\to x$, $x\neq 0$, then $||x_k||\to ||x||$ by continuity of norm function. Therefore,
> $$\dfrac{x^k}{||x^k||^2}\to\dfrac{x}{||x||^2},$$
> i.e,
> $$f(x^k)\to f(x).$$ Concluding that $f$ is a continuous function.

> Note that $f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}$. In fact, let $y=\dfrac{x}{||x||^2}$, the
> $$ ||y||=\dfrac{||x||}{||x||^2}=\dfrac{1}{||x||} \Rightarrow ||x||=\dfrac{1}{||y||}$$
> Therefore, we have that $x=y||x||^2=\dfrac{y}{||y||^2}$.
> Thus the continuity of $f^{-1}$ follow by continuity of $f$.

However, I didn't get to show that $f$ is a subjective function.

Comment: Notice that $f\circ f =\operatorname{id}$. In other words, $f$ is its own inverse, geometrically it describes inversion at the unit sphere. You have obtained this, and surjectivity directly follows from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've found a formula for the inverse function of $f$ (although you don't yet know it's defined on the entire codomain), then given $y\neq0$ it would be 'natural' to try find its source using this formula. Indeed, using your formula:

$$f^{-1}(y)=\frac{y}{||y||^2}=t\in\mathbb R^n/\{0\}$$
And you can check (just as you did before) that:
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{||t||^2}=\frac{\frac{y}{||y||^2}}{\frac{1}{||y||^2}}=y$$
And so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: If $t=\dfrac{y}{||y||^2}\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ then $f(t)=\dfrac{t}{||t||^2}=\dfrac{\frac{y}{||y||^2}}{\left\|\frac{y}{||y||^2}\right\|^2}=t$.

Comment: The norm of $t$ is equal to the norm of $\frac{y}{||y||^2}$, which is equal to $\frac{1}{||y||}$, and so both denominators cancel and you're left with $y$. You've seen this yourself when you showed that $f^{-1}=f$